# Как отследить положение мыши?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы только в красной зоне отображало `stop` ?

```js
let oldx = 0;
let oldy = 0;
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
let block = document.querySelector('.block');

content.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  
  if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
    block.innerHTML = 'right';
    if (x > 50) block.innerHTML = 'stop';
  } else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
    block.innerHTML = 'left';
    if (x - 50 < 50) block.innerHTML = 'stop';
  } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
    block.innerHTML = 'down';
    if (y > 50) block.innerHTML = 'stop';
  } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
    block.innerHTML = 'up';
    if (y - 50 < 50) block.innerHTML = 'stop';
  }
  oldx = e.pageX;
  oldy = e.pageY;
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f44;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4f4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Т.е. при наведении на внутренний блок не срабатывало?

Comment: выводило только  stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно навесить `mouseover` и `mouseout` когда курсор над красным блоком и когда курсор покидает зону зеленого блока, выводит stop. А направление движения вычислять только когда курсор внутри зеленого блока..

```js
let oldx = 0;
let oldy = 0;
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
let block = document.querySelector('.block');

content.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  block.innerHTML = 'stop';
})

block.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
  block.innerHTML = 'stop';
})

block.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
    if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
      block.innerHTML = 'right';
    } else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
      block.innerHTML = 'left';
    } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
      block.innerHTML = 'down';
    } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
      block.innerHTML = 'up';
    }
  oldx = e.pageX;
  oldy = e.pageY;
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f44;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4f4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```